# cURL can't download full file

Tags: php, curl

I'm using cURL in PHP to download files using the following code:

```
set_time_limit(0);    
$tmp = __DIR__."\\downloads\\{$this->id}";
$fp = fopen ($tmp, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($this->url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
echo filesize($tmp)."\n";
```

but sometimes the downloaded file size is less than the original (original: 3.2GB, downloaded: 1.1GB), and when using curl form the command line it downloads the file correctly. trying to re-download the file will always have the same result but with small difference in the downloaded file size.

I also tried using:

```
file_put_contents($tmp, fopen($this->url, 'r'));
```

but the result was the same. most files are downloaded correctly but I need to know the reason why this file isn't.

Comment: Maybe some issues with the network? You should look for a solution when you can resume the download when it stops.

Comment: I can download other larger files with no problem, except this file. I assumed that there is a problem with this particular file but it can be downloaded successfully outside PHP using cURL, IDM, and web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try increasing

```
max_execution_time
```

and/or

```
memory_limit
```

in php.ini

Comment: I increased both of them but no success, I also tried calling the command line cURL with 'shell_exec' to resume the download but it stopped immediately with error "(33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume."